# Reuse styles to a renderView twig template sent to an email

Tags: php, twig, symfony4, swiftmailer

Im painfully noob at symfony so pls be nice :c

Hi, what Im trying to do is to send a styled email using swiftmailer. it actually sends stuff correctly but in plain looking way. Im trying to reuse the styles I used in my website, I want something like this:

[image: my objetive]

But this is what I got when I check my email

[image: my results]

Im working with Symfony 4 and this is the function Im using to send emails:

```php
public function contactSend(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->request->all();

        try {
            $body = $this->renderView("mails/contact.html.twig", $data);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new Response($e, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        MailService::send('email', $body, 'You have received a contact email');

        return new Response('Hi');
}
```

Notice that Im using renderView to send a rendered twig file and there's where I want to reuse my compiled sass styles so I included them in that file:

mails/contact.html.twig:

```
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
```

When I open the file in Chrome it looks pretty but when I send it, it doesn't have any style and Im all lost I dont even know what should I search so I came here, I hope you can help me :C

Comment: I think you need to inline all your styles for emails

Comment: Yeah I think it will do it, but how about font faces?

Comment: I don't really know, maybe you can add as attachment?